# (k+1)th, (k+1)st, k-th+1, or k+1?

Tags: terminology

(Inspired by a [question already at english.SE](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/36512/k1th-or-k1st))

This is more of a terminological question than a purely mathematical one, but can possibly be justified mathematically or simply by just what common practice it. The question is:

When pronouncing ordinals that involve variables, how does one deal with 'one', is it pronounced 'one-th' or 'first'?

For example, how do you pronounce the ordinal corresponding to $k+1$?

There is no such term in mathematics 'infinityeth' (one uses $\omega$, with no affix), but if there were, the successor would be pronounced 'infinity plus oneth'. Which is also 'not a word'.

So then how does one pronounce '$\omega + 1$' which is an ordinal? I think it is simply 'omega plus one' (no suffix, and not 'omega plus oneth' nor 'omega plus first'.

So how ist pronounced, the ordinal corresponding to $k+1$?

- 'kay plus oneth'
- 'kay plus first'
- 'kay-th plus one'
- 'kay plus one'

or something else?

Comment: I use $(k+1)^{st}$ but I can't speak for anyone else. It's easier for me to pronounce, although I guess it is a bad idea if you have variables named $s$ and $t$...

Comment: Community Wiki?

Comment: omega *and* first ?

Comment: I say "kay plus first" though I try to avoid such terms in writing.

Comment: Rejoinder to the @drm65's answer: So, do you say "one-hundred-and-oneth" instead of "one-hundred-and-first"?

Comment: @Theo: It could be pronounced differently, the ordinal for 101 and that for k+1.

Comment: I say ‘kay plus first’ and ‘omega plus first’ if I’m using then as ordinal numbers (adjectives); as cardinal numbers (nouns) they are of course ‘kay plus one’ and ‘omega plus one’.

Comment: Maybe but for me $k+1$ has no semantic difference to $101$ with $k=100$. Hence $(k+1)^{st}$ and $101^{st}$. It was meant to invalidate the bracketing argument.

Comment: As the OP on English.SE, allow me to further ask whether there's a difference between spoken and written math. I've caught a prof in lecture writing (k+1)th at the same time as he said (k+1)st out loud!

Comment: @Qiaochu: How about $(k+1)^{st}$ versus $(k+1)^{\text{st}}$ then?

Comment: @kahen: to be honest, I can barely tell the difference between those two visually.

Comment: Now count further: *kay*, *kay-plus-oneth*, *kay-plus-twoth*, *kay-plus-threeth*, **really?**

Comment: *kay plus oneth* is the only rhyme I know for *month*

Comment: @Qiaochu, I think it is commonly said that it is $n$ plus oneth (I have not come across $n$ plus first). So, perhaps the common extension is to have $k$ plus oneth.

Comment: @kahen: I -can't- tell the difference. What is it?

Comment: @Theo: Yes. Weirdly enough, in fact that's what I often say, though I usually avoid the issue with "the number at position k+1" or similar. (I don't really like the idea that numbers that are 1, 2, or 3 mod 10 should have a special linguistic status. :P)

Comment: @Mitch: The first example has ‘st’ typeset in italic, and the second example has it typeset in roman. The latter is considered preferable as it avoids confusion with exponentiating by $st$... but I think it's still a bad idea so I write $(k+1)$-th.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR: Don't forget "kay-plus-fifth" vs. "kay-plus-fiveth"; the difference (in speaking) isn't only for 1,2, or 3.  Also, we're already stuck with "twenty-first" rather than "twenty-oneth", etc.

Comment: The naive solution: Let $j=k+1$. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want a whole lot of non-expert opinions, you can read the [comments here](http://sbseminar.wordpress.com/2008/03/12/mathematical-grammer-ii/).

Answer (score 13):

From the [Handbook of Writing for the Mathematical Sciences](http://books.google.com/books?id=9gQd2fJA7Y4C&pg=PA63) section 5.5 p. 63:

> Here are examples of how to describe the position of a term in a sequence relative to a variable k:
>
> kth, (k+1)st, (k+2)nd, (k+3)rd, (k+4)th, …
>   (zeroth, first, second, third, fourth, …)
>
> Generally, to describe the term in position k±i for a constant i, you append to (k±i) the ending of the ordinal number for position i (th, st, or nd), which can be found in a dictionary or book of grammar."

So the formal answer is that it should be:

> (k+1)st

Comment: Ah, Higham... :) +1.

Comment: Also, the ordinal for 301 is pronounced "three hundred and first".